# Fill two-dimensional array with Chars from String Input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a basic game of Tic Tac Toe, accepting player input in the form of a string (i.e. a2). The first char is made into an int called row depending on the letter, the same being said for the second char into col (for array grid[row][col]). I have a block of code that throws a custom exception in the event that the first char isn't a, b, or c, and if the second char isn't 1, 2, or 3:

```
if(input == null) {
        throw new NullInputException();
    }
    else if(input.length() != 2) {
        throw new InvalidInputException();
    }
    else if(!(input.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("a") &&
            input.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("b") &&
            input.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("c") ||
            input.substring(1).equals("1") &&
            input.substring(1).equals("2") &&
            input.substring(1).equals("3"))) {
        throw new InvalidInputException();
    }
```

The problem is, this code throws an error even when the input is valid, and I don't know why. I've tried using .charAt() as opposed to .substring(), as well as messed around with my conditional statements. My question is: How do I fix this so that it accepts valid input?

Other questions that just don't help:
[fill two dimensional array with parts of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965436/fill-two-dimensional-array-with-parts-of-a-string);
[fill a 2d array with chars of 2 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585313/fill-a-2d-array-with-chars-of-2-string)

Comment: You are not using `&&` and `||` properly. Also, clarify what this has to do with 2 dimensional arrays.

Comment: According to your code, the only valid input is a string that contains "abc123". Which means any two character input is immediately invalid because it necessarily is missing at least 4 of the other required characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You AND two conditions:

```
input.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("a") &&
            input.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("b")
```

Both cannot be `true` in the same time. That is why the result is always `false` and an exception is thrown.

What you really want is:

```
String first = input.substring(0,1);
String second = input.substring(1);
    if (!((first.equalsIgnoreCase("a") ||
                first.equalsIgnoreCase("b") ||
                first.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) && 
                (second.equals("1") ||
                second.equals("2") ||
                second.equals("3"))) {
        throw new InvalidInputException();
    }
```

Small edit for Neil...

Comment: But with this, to throw the exception, wouldn't the input have to be bad on both parts (i.e. d4)? If the user simply mis-inputted for one char (i.e. c4) then would this catch the error?

Comment: @Alex This only allows a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3. If the input is not one of those, then it is invalid.

Comment: My bad. It worked perfectly. I suppose I was just having an issue with my logic. As for the downvoter, care to explain? The solution was perfect.

Comment: It seems that I am the down-voter, but I have absolutely no idea how it happened.  I am happy to upvote to rectify this, but the site requires @vojta to edit his answer first since some time has passed since this happened.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is better to write a series of simpler tests which are easier to read and verify

```
row = input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
col = input.substring(1);
boolean validRow = (row.equals("A") ||
                    row.equals("B") ||
                    row.equals("C"));
boolean validCol =
        (col.equals("1") ||
        col.equals("2") ||
        col.equals("3"));

if(!(validRow && validCol)) {
```